# Nginx as a reverse proxy and static/dynamic content server at the same time?

Tags: php, nginx

Can I use the same Nginx installation as a reverse proxy (for apache+mod_wsgi) and use it to serve static content and PHP over a single IP address at the same time?

Comment: I would try to ask this question on stackoverflow.com. There it's all about servers. I have a few questions on the subject.

Comment: You but you would need to run apache on a different port (ex 81) and forward traffic from nginx to apache on port 81. Plenty of info on the nginx site how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use one nginx instance to serve both static content, dynamic content (by proxying to an FCGI or backend HTTP app server) and a reverse proxy.  The configuration is straightforward and covered by the excellent documentation and examples available from http://wiki.nginx.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Using different listen ports and redirecting incoming connections (for e. g., with firewall) properly.

Comment: Is it possible with a single instance of nginx only listening on port 80?

Comment: Define what 'single instance of nginx' is? No apache at all, or what?

Comment: What I meant was a single process, sorry. Actually multiple processes would be fine, but all requests need to come from port 80

Comment: — Well, in conclusion: there's nothing unusual in the scheme of nginx usage you had asked about.